# Chrome Console: reload page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there any way to reload chrome page (like clicking F5) from command line of chrome developer console?

I've tired searching but without effect...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
location.reload()
```

<sub>That was easy...</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
history.go()
```

this is probably the shortest way